# Symfony2 acceptance test not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-routing

At the moment, I am writing acceptance test cases for Symfony2 application. I am doing following.

```
namespace my\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

But it cases is failing on looking into following log file.

```
app/logs/test.log
```

It appears that

```
[2016-09-06 12:56:58] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice: "Undefined index: SERVER_PROTOCOL" at /var/www/src/my/Bundle/projectBundle/Helper/DataHelper.php line 139 {"exception":"[object] (PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice(code: 8): Undefined index: SERVER_PROTOCOL at /var/www/src/my/Bundle/projectBundle/Helper/DataHelper.php:139)"} []
```

It appears that `$_SERVER` variable is missing some values in it. Any clues or is there any better ways to write the test cases.

DataHelper.php

```
public function getCanonicalUrl()
    {
        $router = $this->container->get('router');
        $req = $this->container->get('request');
        $route = $req->get('_route');
        if (!$route) {
            return 'n/a';
        }
        $url = $router->generate($route, $req->get('_route_params'));
        $protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        return $protocol . ($this->getHostname() . $url);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you pass https => true as an argument ?

Comment: @COil is it really matters? with problem?

Comment: can you show the code of the DataHelper.php class?

Comment: @Matteo Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your solutions is working but a better approach could be the following:

Reading the [doc about symfony2 testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html):

More about the request() Method:

> The full signature of the request() method is:
>
> ```
> request(
>     $method,
>     $uri,
>     array $parameters = array(),
>     array $files = array(),
>     array $server = array(),
>     $content = null,
>     $changeHistory = true
> )
> ```
>
> The server array is the raw values that you'd expect to normally find
>   in the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal.

So probably a more cleaner approach could be:

```
$client->request(
    'GET',
    '/',
    array(),
    array(),
    array(
        'SERVER_PROTOCOL'          => 'http://',
    )
);
```

One problem could be about the value you are setting in the `SERVER_PROTOCOL` variable. Regarding [to the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' Name and revision of the information protocol via
>   which the page was requested; i.e. 'HTTP/1.0';

Seems the real value is `'HTTP/1.0'` (instead of `http://`). So double check the class  `DataHelper.php` that generate the error.

**EDIT:**

You can access to the an HTTP_SERVER variable from the symfony2 request (this in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object))

```
// retrieve $_SERVER variables
$request->server->get('HTTP_SERVER');
```

You can also call the request's method: [getScheme](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getScheme) and [isSecure](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_isSecure) in order to obtain this info (Check the source code of the Request class for example). Probably, in your case, the getScheme method is what you need. As Example:

```
$protocol = $req->getScheme();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I found a more or less workaround for it as of now. As of shown below anyway its a test case.

```
namespace Chip\Bundle\PraxistippsBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = 'http://';

        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I tried following as well.

[Stackoverflow One more Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760568/phpunit-error-undefined-index-http-host)

But a correct solution is open to discussion.

Comment: Or you could modify your DataHelper.php class to test if the protocol key exists or not.

Comment: Or may be reimplement it entirely to not rely on superglobal variables at all.

Comment: When getting SERVER_PROTOCOL , why don't you use the request stack service ?

Comment: At all thank you for the comments. At Coil I can modify one class or two, in case if its used every where and it's difficult to modify every where. Secondly its a testing scenario, but in prod or dev modes that Global Parameters are always present. At zerkms re implement just for testing also not good solution.